# Restcomm Visual Designer project issues when saving

Tags: restcomm

I wrote a new service and things went ok until I started having issue saving my project: I get 'Project saved with validation errors'. I can't see what those errors are and in fact my project wasn't saved. The current version of my prompts are not used by Restcomm that still play an old version.
I can re-write the whole thing but that isn't very nice :(
It sounds like the visual designer would benefit for a commit system so you can go back to a working version and see at what points things went wrong...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Restcomm uses the last successfully saved version of the project, and this version is kept until another version without errors is saved, replacing the previous.
Thank you for your suggestions, i do agree that re-write the whole thing isn't very nice. Thinking about that, a new issue was created to improve the alert messages when some error occur while saving the project:

https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm/issues/670

Also, there is a plan to improve the way RVD provide the project/application to Restcomm, also helping the editing process. I will keep you updated about that.

For now, besides the warning message displayed at the top of the page when a validation error occurs, there is also a warning icon displayed in the verb responsible to trigger the error, that can help to spot what is causing it, like i've tried to show in the image below:

[image: RVD warning icon]

I'll keep updates about improvements on that.

Comment: I think the problem lies with displaying warnings for elements in modules that are not active (not visible). Maybe an additional "exclamation mark" in the label (tab) of these modules would help.